# Ускорение SQL запроса, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Имеется табличка board с полями: cats (тип integer, массив с цифрами: {1,2,3,4}), status, activation, del и прочие столбцы, которые не участвуют в выборке.

На cats стоит индекс типа GIN. Также есть составной индекс на cats, status, activation, del (нужен ли именно такой индекс?), а также составной индекс на status, activation, del (тоже под вопросом). Время выборки по этим полям варьируется от 0.1 до 0.5 секунд. Данных в табличке на данный момент 150 тысяч. Можно ли как-то ускорить выборку?

Пример sql запроса на выборку:

```
    select
   count(*) 
from
   board 
where
   cats @ > '{3}'::integer[] 
   AND status = '1' 
   AND activation = '1' 
   AND del = '0';
```

explain (analyze)

```
Aggregate  (cost=12075.37..12075.38 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=469.175..469.176 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using board_cats_sad_idx on board  (cost=0.42..11952.44 rows=49175 width=0) (actual time=258.491..423.847 rows=49700 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((status = 1) AND (activation = 1) AND (del = 0))
        Filter: (cats @> '{3}'::integer[])
        Rows Removed by Filter: 108857
        Heap Fetches: 34645
Planning time: 0.238 ms
Execution time: 469.218 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

Реализация `MVCC` всегда больно сказывается на `count`. Ведь нельзя просто взять и подсчитать число строк, необходимо проверить каждую подходящую строку и её скрытые версии на видимость в этой конкретной транзакции. Поэтому `count` большого числа строк лучше не делать вовсе, а завести табличку с предаггрегированными счётчиками и читать оттуда. Обновлять счётчики можно триггерами или планировщиком считать дельту - зависит от требований к актуальности данных.

Отдельно упомяну, что требования актуальности `realtime` банально бессмысленны. Если у вас сотня строк меняется в секунду, а база считает выборку 0,5с - значит циферка будет приблизительная всегда. Нет, она конечно будет точно показывать число строк которое нашла. Но пользователю-то с этого какой прок, если он увидит циферку спустя ещё какое-то время пока отработает уже само ваше приложение?

---

Ну а если идти к представленному запросу:

1. оценка планировщика достаточно точна, что не может не радовать.
2. используется `Index Only Scan`, то есть табличка меняется довольно редко. И, следовательно, не будет очень дорого поддерживать таблицу счётчиков триггером.
3. фильтр по `cats` отрезает 2/3 всех строк оставшихся после индекса
4. `count` отработал достаточно быстро и запрос упирается не в него
5. используется индекс `board_cats_sad_idx`. Не могу сказать, который именно это индекс. Судя по `Index Only Scan` вероятно это `btree( cats, status, activation, del)` имеющий здесь смысл только из-за `Index Only Scan`.

Прикладной интерес может быть в пункте 3, для чего необходимо понимать, какие фильтры динамичны и должны быть в индексах, а какие являются статичным дополнением. Дальше варианты строятся на основе этого. Если только `cats` различаются, то целесообразен частичный

```
gin(cats) where status = 1 AND activation = 1 AND del = 0
```

Все 3 условия как-то не выглядят селективными, но если есть что-то селективное, то можно поставить [btree_gin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gin.html) расширение и добавить поле в gin индекс

```
gin(cats, status) where activation = 1 AND del = 0
```

Если статично у вас условие как раз по `cats` - то можно его использовать как префикс частичного индекс

```
btree(status) where cats @ > '{3}'::integer[] AND activation = 1 AND del = 0
```

И прочие варианты, основанные на вашем знании своей задачи и распределения данных.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. С postgresql знаком не так давно. Почитаю про триггеры и про все остальное.

Comment: Может имеются какие-нибудь утилиты для ускорения postgresql? По идее на сервер (digitalocean) можно поставить что угодно.

Comment: Взрослые СУБД - это то, чем надо учиться пользоваться хорошо. Или приглашать людей, которым это интересно и уже умеют - DBA это вполне себе отдельная специализация. Потому что СУБД - это не вещь в себе, а большая и весьма сложная система напрямую связанная с вашими данными.

Comment: Лучше учиться, чем кого-то приглашать.

Установить PostgreSQL на сервер смог, сконвертировать с mysql и импортировать смог, переписать под PostgreSQL смог (более менее). Буду дальше изучать.

Answer (score 0):

Выложите свой план на https://explain.depesz.com/ и просмотрите там. У вас используется индекс и потом делается count(), а мы все помним, что count - не самая быстрая операция в PostgreSQL, к сожалению.

Можно поэкспериментировать с индексами, но, не уверен, что тут можно реально сделать быстрее, при таком подходе.

Comment: но считать то как-то надо. Выложил https://explain.depesz.com/s/6PAX